# Ellipsis control when printing h5py dataset slices

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

Let's say you have a h5py dataset `ds` that's a 1D array that's thousands of entries long. If you do

```
print(ds[:])
```

python will print the first three and last three entries with an ellipsis in between. But if your ds length is less than 1000 it won't. How do you adjust that 1000 length limit? I want it to give me the ellipsis if it's more than, say, 20 entries. For example in pandas one can adjust this via the `pd.options.display.max_rows` option. What's the method in h5py?

Comment: `ds[:]` is a numpy array.  So is the `numpy` print control that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, above, use `np.set_printoptions()` to control printing options. Two of most interest to you are:

- **`threshold=`** controls # of array items that triggers a summary print (default=1000).
- **`edgeitems=`** controls # of array items printed at the beginning and end of summarized print (default 3).

Example to reduce the threshold to 20:
**`np.set_printoptions(threshold=20)`**